# Unable to access environment variables into a bash shell script in GitHub Workflow

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have a GitHub Workflow that runs a bash script.

The bash script itself has two prompts with the first one asking for `INPUT_ENV` (amr_qa) in this case and the second one asking for `UID_ID` (1234).

When I run this script from GitHub, how do I pass the GitHub env variables to the script?

[image]

[image]

I have tried to add:

```
env:
```

within the same GitHub workflow steps block but it never got passed in.

I have also tried to add a function within my script to ingest the Github workflow user input variables but that did not do the job either.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add text instead of images. In a separate Bash script, the `${{...}}` expressions are not resolved so that's expected. These expressions are only resolved in the current workflow YAML. After setting with `env`, use with `$VAR` syntax in the called scripts and that should work.

Comment: Thanks for helping me edit the post. My internet went out yesterday and I wasn't able to fix it in time. And I appreciate your solution as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set env like below

```
- name: "Set Environment Variables"
  run: |
    echo "ENTER_ENV=${{ inputs.ENTER_ENV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "ENTER_XSD_UID=${{ inputs.ENTER_XSD_UID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: "Run Upload Script"
  run: |
    echo chmod +x .github/scripts/upload.sh
    echo .github/scripts/upload.sh
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue. I couldn't find documentation anywhere to specify the use of ">> $GITHUB_ENV" :)

Answer (score 0):

The expressions `${{...}}` are only expanded in the YAML workflow itself and not in any of the called scripts. As you're trying to use the `inputs` context in a script, it won't expand which is expected.

After setting `env` using `inputs` context should work fine; and, you should be able to use the environment variables using `$VAR` or `${VAR}` syntax.

Example:

```yaml
- name: Run script
  env:
    ENTER_XSD_UID: ${{ inputs.ENTER_XSD_UID }}
    ENTER_ENV: ${{ inputs.ENTER_ENV }}
  shell: bash
  run: |
    chmod +x ./.github/scripts/upload.sh
    ./.github/scripts/upload.sh
```